# Why i always have to use this command "$ source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root" for opening "Anaconda-navigator"

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, anaconda3

[see the terminal image to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMogC.png)

geetansh@geetansh-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S145-15IWL:~$ anaconda-navigator
anaconda-navigator: command not found
geetansh@geetansh-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S145-15IWL:~$ source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root
(base) geetansh@geetansh-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S145-15IWL:~$ anaconda-navigator

Answer (score 1):

`anaconda-navigator` is not in your environment path. This is why your system doesn't know what it should execute.

Try this:

```bash
echo $PATH # this will show your environment path
source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root
which anaconda-navigator # shows you the path
```

You will see that the anaconda-navigator path is not in your environment path.
With `source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root` you execute a script, which also set your environment path so that you could execute anaconda-navigator without  the path.

```bash
cat -n ~/anaconda3/bin/activate # That will show you what else the script will do, if execute
```

```bash
export PATH="/home/geetansh/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" # this will include
# the anaconda3 binary path in your environment path.
```

---

If you don't want to extend `PATH`, you could also write a script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root
anaconda-navigator
```

You could execute it with `sh yourScript.sh` or you could make it executable with `chmod +x yourScript.sh` and execute it with ./yourScript.sh.
If you want more convenience, you could write an alias for your script.

```bash
echo "alias yourScript='~/PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT/yourScript.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```

.bashrc is executed after you start the shell. So if you just had written something in .bashrc, you have to restart your shell you do:

```bash
source ~/.bashrc
```

I hope it is now clear what `source` does.

Comment: source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate it works for me while using ubuntu lts